# コンソールのページコードをEUCにしたい

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, 文字コード

## 状況

現在PowerShellのコードページはshift-jisです。

PowershellのSSH機能を使用し、リモートサーバーにログインしたいと考えています。

ただ、サーバー環境がLinuxであり、文字コードはEUCです。
そのため、PowerShellのコンソールコードページをEUCに変換したいということです。

## 問題

PowershellでEUCにコードページを指定しても指定できません。
(下記のページを参考に `51932` はEUCの文字コードと確認)

参考:
[Windows 文字コードページ一覧 (Windows Tips)](https://www.ipentec.com/document/windows-codepage-list)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 解決したいこと

コンソールのページコードを任意で指定することはできないのでしょうか？
また、指定する方法を知っている方がいれば教えて欲しいと思います。

Comment: この記事 [目的の文字コードに合ったEncodingオブジェクトを取得する](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/string/getencodingobject.html) にある、`20932`で`chcp`を試してみてはどうでしょう？ 少なくとも変更は出来たようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
こちらで、調査したところ別の部分に問題があるようでした...。
sshでログイン後、文字コードが勝手に65001(UTF-8)に切り替わってしまうようです。

確認手順としては

①ページコード変換932→20932
②sshコマンドでログイン
③コンソール画面→プロパティ→オプションタブ→現在のコードページを確認

Comment: 変化した状況と、最終的にやりたいことに合わせて、質問を編集してみてください。その状況ですと私の方は知識が無いので、わかる人に届く質問にした方が良いでしょう。蛇足ですがTeraTermとかの別ソフトではダメなのでしょうか？そうした事情も追加すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 私はターミナルソフトにはRloginを使用しています。しかし「ちょっとしたこと」をやるには、Powershellは常時立ち上げてあるので、PowerShellで統一して作業を行いたいと思ったことがきっかけです。
他質問者様への回答理由を持って自己解決としたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問の内容が変わってきそうですが、21932と50932についてまとめておきます。

---

[Console Code Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages)で説明されていますが、レジストリの

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
```

に登録されているコードページしか使えません。そしてここには50932はなく、21932があがっています。ちなみに21932と50932には

- 21932

  - [IBM拡張文字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97)などが文字化けする
  - [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte)など標準APIで使用できる
  - IE付属の`MLang.dll`[の`ConvertINetUnicodeToMultiByte`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741107(v%3Dvs.85))などで使用できる
- 50932

  - IBM拡張文字なども正しく扱える
  - `WideCharToMultiByte`など標準APIで使用できない
  - IE付属の`MLang.dll`の`ConvertINetUnicodeToMultiByte`などで使用できる

と微妙な差があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

自PCのレジストリを見ましたが、50932は含まれていませんでした。(UTF-8 65001もなかったのですが...)

PowerShellコンソールのコードページは以下のレジストリに保存されるようです。
コンピューター\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe

直接レジストリ操作を行いましたが、この場合コンソール表示で自分が入力した文字は表示されなくなりました。
私はエンコーディング処理だけの問題かと思ったのですが...。根が深い問題なのかもしれません。

解決は出来なさそうなので、上記の検証をもって自己解決とします。